# Comparing two dictionary keys and values

Tags: python-2.7, loops, dictionary, key

I have two dictionaries in which i'm trying to first find the matching key from d1 in d2, then output the subtraction of the 3rd value in that key from both dictionaries..can this be done in one loop function? first i tried doing it in two steps but this gives me an empty list for d3, then I tried to use a loop but it gives me error that v is not defined.

```
d1 = {'alpha': [5, 9, 11], 'beta': [6, 10, 20], 'gamma': [12, 15, 19]}
d2 = {'alpha': [3, 8, 20], 'omega': [15, 32, 40], 'ro': [22, 25, 4]}

d3 = {}
for key in d1:
    if key in d2:
        d3.setdefault(key, []).append
print d3
#Should be d3 = {'alpha': [3, 8, 20]}

#Compare and Calculate the difference between 20 and 11 in the alpha key
value = d3(key, v(2)) - d1(key, v(2))
print value
#value = 9

#Can a loop just find the key in d2 and that matches key in d1
#and calculate the difference?
for key in d1:
    if key in d2:
        value = d2(key, v(2)) - d1(key, v(2))
        print value
```

Thoughts?

Thank you.
-Jon

Comment: not only, `v` is not defined but `d1` and `d2` are not functions, so you cannot  write `d1(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
diff = {key: d2[key][2] - d1[key][2] for key in d2 if key in d1}
# {'alpha': 9}
```

This will give you a dictionary in which all keys are common to `d2` and `d1` and the values are the difference of the third values in the lists of `d1` and `d2`

Comment: Thanks!  I knew there was a way to do it like that but I wasn't sure the exact syntax.